# When using symfony2's form type "collection", how can I validate that at least one form has been submitted?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I used [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.htm) to embed a collection of forms. How can I add validation that will ensure that the form is submitted with at least one form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a [callback function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html), call [count](http://php.net/count) on your collection.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Comment: I found that even when I don't submit anything related to the embedded collection, the ArrayCollection that gets passed into the validator still has all the objects originally bound attached. Did you just do a count of values you know those entities should have (which obviously aren't set), or should my validation be cascading better? The null values are @Assert\NotBlank on the entities that are in the collection.

Answer (score 8):

Symfony now has a `Count` constraint that can be used with collection types to set a minimum number of items:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

$formBuilder->add('example', CollectionType::class, [
  // other options...
  'constraints' => [
    new Assert\Count([
      'min' => 1,
      'minMessage' => 'Must have at least one value',
      // also has max and maxMessage just like the Length constraint
    ]),
  ],
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should make at least one field from this form required in form Type class or as Assert annotation in Entity class?